# How can I make the Adobe flashplugin use Pulseaudio under Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound, kubuntu, flash, external-soundcard

I have trouble getting the sound from firefox to output in an external (USB) sound card.  I understand there are some issues around getting flash to play sound here from googling the question, but I was unable to find a concrete answer on how I can solve my problem.